# Can't get a notification when connecting an external accessory to the 3.5 mm headphones jack

Tags: ios, headphones, external-accessory

I've been trying to get this to work for a while now.
I've done everything they say in the documentation and still got nothing.

This is the code in my app delegate that registers for local notifications:

```
- (void) registerForLocalNotifications {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(_accessoryConnected:)
                                             name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
                                           object:nil];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(_accessoryDisconnected:)
                                             name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications]; }
```

The above is called from applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Here is the code of the connect/disconnect methods:

```
- (void) _accessoryConnected:(NSNotification *)notification {
          NSLog(@"_accessoryConnected"); }

- (void) _accessoryDisconnected:(NSNotification*)notification {
NSLog(@"_accessoryDisconnected"); }


-(void) accessoryDidDisconnect:(EAAccessory *) accessory {
NSLog(@"accessoryDidDisconnect"); }
```

Tried connecting the headphones that come with the iPhone and got nothing, same for my external accessory I want to integrate with the app.

Please help,
Thanks,
Shaul.

Comment: Well, after doing some more reading I see that the headphones jack isn't supported in the external accessory framework. Is there any other framework I can use? Please anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use AudioSessionPropertyListener for this.
EAAccessory notifications are for hardware that connects to the 30 pin port.
Add this listener in viewDidLoad and remove it in ViewDidUnLoad

```
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, audioSessionPropertyListener, nil);
```

Add the following methods in the view controller.

```
BOOL isHeadsetPluggedIn() {
    UInt32 routeSize = sizeof (CFStringRef);
    CFStringRef route;

    OSStatus error = AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute,
                                              &routeSize,
                                              &route
                                              );    
    NSLog(@"%@", route);
    return (!error && (route != NULL) && ([(NSString*)route rangeOfString:@"Head"].location != NSNotFound));
}

void audioSessionPropertyListener(void* inClientData, AudioSessionPropertyID inID,
                                  UInt32 inDataSize, const void* inData) {
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;

    // Determines the reason for the route change, to ensure that it is not
    //      because of a category change.
    CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = inData;    
    CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef = CFDictionaryGetValue (routeChangeDictionary,CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason));

    SInt32 routeChangeReason;    
    CFNumberGetValue (routeChangeReasonRef, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &routeChangeReason);

    // "Old device unavailable" indicates that a headset was unplugged, or that the
    //  device was removed from a dock connector that supports audio output. 
    if (routeChangeReason != kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable)
        return;

    if (!isHeadsetPluggedIn()) 
    {
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
    }
    else 
    {
        UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
    }    
}
```

Note, I got this code long ago from somewhere and it worked for me. Cannot attribute the source now as I don't know where I got it from.

Comment: Tried to manage with this C code but it's been years since I touched C. Saw there's an alternative called AVAudioSession in Objective-C. Do you think I can do the same with this? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240

Comment: Ok I managed to get this code you posted to work, but it works only when the headset isn't connected to the device before the app starts. Any ideas why is that?

Comment: Call isHeadsetPluggedIn on viewDidLoad as well. The above code calls it only when audio route change notification is received.

Comment: I simply missed initialization of the audio session. That was the real problem. It needs to come before anything else related to audio sessions. After I added that, everything started working.